# socket io no emite en una petición HTTP

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

Estoy aprendiento flask y estoy intentando emitir un mensaje por sockets cuando llega una petición HTTP, pero al parecer no funciona.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET'] = 'secret'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    socketio.emit('code', {"data":"code"}, broadcast=True) # aqui no funciona

    return render_template('index.html') 

@socketio.on('my event')
def handle_my_custom_event(json):
    print('received json: ' + str(json))
    socketio.emit('code', {"data":"code"}, broadcast=True) # aqui funciona
```

qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Las rutas creadas con `@app.route` son HTTP "normal", pensadas para un intercambio petición-respuesta. No soportan el protocolo socketio. Creo que solo las rutas declaradas con `@socketio.on` pueden enviar o recibir datos via websocket.

Comment: Pero puedes hacer que el index.html que retorna la ruta `/` contenga javascript que inicie un websocket hacia otra ruta que hayas declarado con `@socketio.on`. Así, cuando el navegador pida / recibirá una página que abrirá la conexión socketio y por la que ya podrás comunicarte.